# How to use ReadString Macro x86 Assembly(NASM)

Tags: assembly, macros, x86, nasm, intel

I have been trying all weekend to figure this out and I have finally come to StackOverflow to try and get some answers.

Goal: Prompt user to enter a string, store string in memory and print it out. <<-- Simple! But I am so new at assembly I am getting tripped up over storing the users input. All I thought was needed were 2 macros - `WriteString` and `ReadString`. This is what I have so far:

```
%include "CPsub32.inc"
%include "Macros_CPsub32.inc"  ; needed to use the ReadString and WriteString macros

section .data  ; Declaration of labels 
type:   db 0Ah,0Dh, 'Type Here:',0Ah,0Dh,OOh     ;String plus CRLF

section .text
        global main

main    equ   $          ; main, start of program

        mov edx, type    ; Moves the contents of the label type into the edx register
        call WriteString ; Prints contents of edx
        call ReadString  ; Prompts for users input

My Exit equ  $           ; Exit program
        Exit 0
```

Now, my main question: how do I take the users input, store it in memory and then print it back to the screen?

One way I thought I could accomplish this was to take `ReadString` after I called it and move it to the edx register, but that didn't work. I tried playing around with `WriteString` and `ReadString` in many different positions, but, again all were fails. Is there a way in assembly where I could store the users input into a variable and then move that into a register? I know what I want to do, but don't know the tools I need in order to do it.

I know this is a very simple fix for a very simple problem. I am a super beginner at assembly and am used to OOP so I'm having a very challenging time. I've tried looking up how to use the `ReadString` macro but I really couldn't find clear instructions on it. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advanced!! :)

Comment: Does this help? http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Assembly/Q_24594784.html

Comment: It seems like it totally would since it's my same exact question, but I don't want to put my credit card info in for the free trial :/

Comment: What? I didn't get *anything* like that at all. I'm running Chrome with Adblock and Adblock plus though. Sorry the website isn't avaliable to you

Comment: Without seeing your CPsub32.inc (got a link?) it is impossible to say. I would guess that `ReadString` needs two parameters - a buffer(which you'll need to declare), and a length (maximum length to put in the buffer - no gets()!). Typically, buffer in edx and length in ecx, but who knows?

Comment: I don't think I can get a link for you. I'm connecting to my professors Unix via PuTTY so I'm going through his computer directory for everything. So this all seems like a huge black box to me. I'll try playing around with the buffer...perhaps I can try to make a stack and get the data from there.

Comment: Okay, go through your instructor's directory looking for documentation. If it isn't there, knock on his door! Or re-read what you do have, keeping in mind that ReadString almost certainly needs a buffer and a maximum length. You won't have to "make a stack" - you've got one. You can subtract enough from `esp` to make a buffer on the stack. I think `buf resb BUFSIZ` (in `section .bss` - which you'll have to add) would be easier. (BUFSIZ equ 80 - or some number, anywhere in your code - use it both to declare the buffer and to feed to ReadString to make sure they match)